# how to make byte value be used as int

Tags: c#, user-interface, int, byte

I'm trying to make server be able to received client byte and use it as integer, how can I do that? this is the code I'm try to fix~ the only error is that it cannot process the byte to int... please help me

```
try
             { 

                byte[] received = new byte[1024];
                mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
                updateUI("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));


                int Cir;
                Cir = received;

                switch (Cir)
                {
                    case 1 :
                        serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
                        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                        serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                        serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
                        serialPort1.Open();
                        serialPort1.Write("a");
                        serialPort1.Close();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
                        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                        serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                        serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
                        serialPort1.Open();
                        serialPort1.Write("a");
                        serialPort1.Close();
                        break;


                }
```

Comment: You are trying to convert an *array* to an int. That's of course not possible. Impossible to guess what was intended, received[0] just gives a random byte of the ones that were received.  Do **not** ignore the return value of Read().

Comment: well actually the client I set it to only sent a specific number to the server to execute the case according to number. Can you teach me or give me idea, how to able the server read int or char instead byte. at the command  byte[] received = new byte[1024];
                mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try converting the byte value and setting your int to it that way
int cir = Convert.ToInt32(recieved);
```

[Converting to Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hk2thbx.aspx)

Comment: i try your method, it doesn't give any error anymore, but its stop the server.

Comment: can u instead teach me how can i convert the byte into int and display it, maybe this will give me an idea to another method.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try writing the value in a console to see what you have
Console.WriteLine(received);
Console.Readline();
```

Alternatively, if you're using and IDE like Visual Studios you may be able to stop the function mid execution and check the values.